# Файлы, задано n ключевых слов

Tags: c

Задано n ключевых слов. Разработать програму, которая

1. Создает текстовый файл TF1 с символьными рядами разной длины в которой слова разделены пробелами.
2. Читает вместимое файла TF1 и записывает в файл TF2 Только те ряды в которых есть хотя бы одно ключевое слово(если таких нет, в файл TF2 Помещается оповещение об этом.
3. Читает вместимое файла TF2 И печатает его по рядам

Вот мой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string.h>

 FILE *TF1, *TF2;
 int i=1;
input(){
    char a[300];
    gets(a);
    fputs(a,TF1);
    memset(a, 0, 300);
    printf("\n 1 - Next row || 2 - End rows ");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    fputs(" ",TF1);
}
void main(){
    int j=0,k=0,flag=0,st=0;
    char a[300],*b,h,word[300]="ipsum";
    TF1 = fopen("TF1.txt","w");
    input();
    while (i==1){
        fputs("\n",TF1);
        scanf("%d",h);
        input();
    }
     fclose(TF1);
   TF1 = fopen("TF1.txt","r");
    TF2 = fopen("TF2.txt","w");
 if (TF1 == NULL) perror ("Error opening file");
   else {
     while (!feof(TF1))
     {
         if(fscanf (TF1, "%s", a)!= 1)
         {
             perror("File is empty");
         return -1;
         }
         wordsearch(a);
        if(!strcmp(a, word))
            {
            printf("%s\n", a);  st++;
            }
    }
     if(!st) puts("The word was not found");
      b=strtok(a,"0");
    if(b==0)fprintf(TF2,"No selected words");
    while (b!=0){
        fprintf(TF2,"%s\n",b);
        b=strtok(0,"0");
    }
    memset(a, 0, 300);
     fclose (TF2);
   }
TF2=fopen("TF2.txt","r");
    int X=0;
    while (!(feof(TF2)))
        fscanf(TF2,"%c",&a[X++]);
    printf("Main Words:\n");
    puts(a);

}
void wordsearch(char* w)
{
    int i = strlen(w), st = 0;
    char *ch = w;
    while(i)
    {
        if(isalpha(*(w + i)))
            break;
        i--;
    }
    *(w + i + 1) = '\0';
    while(*w)
    {
        if(isalpha(*w)) st = 1;
        if(st)
          *(ch++) = *w ;
    w++;
    }
    *ch = '\0';
}
```

Проблема в том, что он не записывает мне в файл TF2 Ничего + не выходил сделать ввод ключевых слов с клавиатуры

Answer (score 1):

> Проблема в том

Проблема в том, что то, что Вы написали - очень далеко от постановки задачи. Я бы не стал даже разбираться, но Ваша героическая попытка заслуживает уважения. Поэтому, попытаюсь ответить.

> не выходил сделать ввод ключевых слов с клавиатуры

И не надо! Ключевые слова надо держать в отдельном файле. А то Вы замучаетесь их вводить каждый раз.

Я написал комменты - думаю, что всё понятно:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//-----------------------------------------
// Ввод списка ключевых слов
//-----------------------------------------
int input_key(char *key_wrd[]) {
   FILE * FK;
   int n = 0, len;
   char *cp;
   char a[30];

   FK = fopen("KEY.txt","r");
   if(FK == NULL) {
      printf("Ошибка при открыти файла!\n");
      perror("KEY.txt");
      return -1;
   }

   // Читаем список клюевых слов
   while (1) {
      cp = fgets(a, 30, FK);   // Считаем, что по слову на строку
      if (cp == NULL) break;
      len = strlen(a);
      a[len-1] = '\0'; // Замазали символ '\n'
      len --;
      key_wrd[n] = malloc(len); // Выделили память под ключевое слово
      strncpy(key_wrd[n], a, len); // Запомнили ключевое слово
      n++;
   }

   fclose(FK);
   return n;
}


//-----------------------------------------
// Проверка наличия ключевых слов в строке
//-----------------------------------------
int test_kw(char *a, char *key_wrd[], int n) {
   int k;

   for(k=0; k<n; k++) {
      if ( strstr(a, key_wrd[k]) != NULL) {
         // Обнаружено вхождение ключевого слова
         return 1;
      }
   }

   // Ключевых слов не найдено
   return 0;
}

//--------------------------
// Главная функция
//--------------------------
int main(int srgc, char *argv[]){

FILE *F1, *F2;       // Обрабатываемые файлы
char a[300];         // Буфер под одну строку
char *cp;
char *key_wrd[50]; // Не более 50 ключевых слов
int n_key;          // Сколько реально ввели ключевых слов
int rc;

// Загружаем ключевые слова
   n_key = input_key(key_wrd);
   if (n_key < 1) {
      printf("Список ключевых слов пуст.\n");
      return -1;
   }
   printf("Список ключевых слов содержит %d слов\n", n_key);

// Открываем файлы
   F1 = fopen("F1.txt","r");
   if(F1 == NULL) {
      printf("Ошибка при открыти файла!\n");
      perror("F1.txt");
      return -1;
   }

   F2 = fopen("F2.txt","w");
   if(F2 == NULL) {
      printf("Ошибка при открыти файла!\n");
      perror("F2.txt");
      return -1;
   }

// Выполняем обработку
   printf("Начинаем бработку!\n");
   while (1) {
      // Читаем очередную строку
      cp = fgets(a, 300, F1);
      if (cp == NULL) {
        printf("Обработка закончена!\n");
        break;
      }
      // Проверяем наличие ключевых слов
      rc = test_kw(a, key_wrd, n_key);
      if (rc > 0) {
         // Ключевые слова обнаружены
         fputs(a, F2);
      } else {
         // Ключевых слов нет
         fputs("Ключевых слов нет.\n", F2);
      }
   } 

// Закрываем файлы

   fclose(F1);
   fclose(F2);
}
```

Comment: насколько я понял, ваш код подразумевает то, что файлы уже созданы, и в них уже есть текст

Comment: Да. В качестве проверяемого файла я взял файл исходного текста этой программы, а в качестве файла ключей набил пять строк, вроде:  int, while, else, return...